# Liquibase Running as a Kubernetes job is failing to get connected with Postgres container

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, liquibase, kubernetes-helm

Setting up minikube cluster with the postgress and liquibase.
--> postgres is deployed in the pods 
--> Running liquibase job to update the postgres

kubernetes job file to run update command in liquibase:

[image: kubernetes job file to run update command in liquibase]

Dockerfile to create a liquibase image:

[image: Dockerfile to create a liquibase image]

error log:

[image: error log]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551 and the accepted answer

Comment: please do not use screenshots :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is resolved .. giving the refrence of the internal end point of the Postgres pod :)

Answer (score 0):

The pod is not able to establish connection to the database. Make sure database username and password is correct. Instead of setting , localhost in LIQUIBASE_URL in DockerFile, can you provide the IP here. Also try to exec into the pod and check if you are able to ping the machine where database is hosted.